# Mysql request creating multiple records on insert issue

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

Will try to explain my issue in 2 words. I have an address like that.

```
https://example.com/update/?web=SecondString
```

and have a code like that

```
if ($_GET['web']) {         

echo $_GET['web']; // will show SecondString

$db = new \PDO('*********');
$dbQuery = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO traf(website, count) VALUES(:web, 1)');
$dbQuery->bindParam(':web', $_GET['web']);        
$dbQuery->execute();
exit;
```

}

and the database showing me that

[image]

in case of

```
$db->prepare('INSERT INTO traf(website, count) VALUES("MYSTRING", 1)');
```

everything is ok!

can someone explain to me what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some form that submits on every change to the input field? Use the "Network" inspector to see what your browser client is doing as I suspect it's sending more requests than you realize.

Comment: @tadman it's just a simple url without any forms etc. Just navigating it and that's it... It's can be a issue with nginx or some settings but i'm not sure

Comment: Look at your network traffic. Until you know that's not the issue, I suspect it is. I've seen this before with an over-eager auto-submit JavaScript snippet. Doing this accidentally in PHP is highly unlikely, as you'd have to write a loop and do a lot of `substr` calls, like it would take serious effort to foul up this badly. With JavaScript, though, putting it in the `onChange` handler instead of `onClick` or `onSubmit` will do precisely this.

Comment: @tadman there is no script or something else on this page. Just a code i showed you on a main post

Comment: I get that, but that code won't do *anything* unless a request is made. Look at the requests being made.

Comment: @tadman you can try it yourself.. it's nothing in a network trafic
https://api.cursor.style/update/?web=thisisastring

Comment: @tadman trust me i know how php work there is no scripts or something as i told you.. i sent you a link and you can check it. The code inside index.php is simple as on top. Just navigating to this url can't made more requests that one per navigation

look on screen just one "enter pressed" and that's it will give me t..te...tes...test...
https://prnt.sc/q92hdb

Comment: You're going to need to do some logging server-side to see *exactly* what requests you're receiving and what data you're inserting. This data doesn't just magically appear without explanation. As it stands, the *only way* that can be inserted as you describe is if a request came through with `?web=S`, then `?web=Se` and so on. Check your logs. Add more debugging code if you must.

Comment: @tadman https://prnt.sc/q92hue as you can see there is no loop here. There is no script's on a link https://api.cursor.style/update/?web=thisisastring etc. 

Just a simple code https://prnt.sc/q92hue

Comment: @tadman in this case everything is ok.. that's mean there is no additional requests..

$db->prepare('INSERT INTO traf(website, count) VALUES("MYSTRING", 1)');

Comment: @tadman Gosh i finally find out wtf was that! That was a fuk.g stupid "Chrome Extension" making request every time i hit enter

Answer (score 2):

The reasons was a chrome extension which made additional requests.... I killed all day to find out that.

Comment: Good job catching it. One way to catch these faster is to try other browsers (e.g. Firefox) or use tools like `curl` to narrow down probabilities.

Comment: @tadman agree with you but i can't even imaging that some extension can make an additional requests

Comment: Extensions can do a lot of things you wouldn't expect. That's why you need to be really selective about which are enabled.